# how to delete items in listbox c#

Tags: c#

im trying to add items in listbox with database values, and trying to remove it by using doubleclick event, i want to remove items in listbox and the price of that item will deduct to the txtTotal.Text. for example. i add a items in listbox name "Package1" with the Price of 299 and add another item name "Package2" with the price of 300, if i remove "Package1", the txtTotal will decrease a number of 299 and it will become 300.

here's my code:

```
void fillCombo()
    {

        string constring = "server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        string Query = "Select * from dbinfo.tbladvance;";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDB = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            myReader = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string sName = myReader.GetString("Names");
                comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);



            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        string Query = "Select * from dbinfo.tbladvance where Names='" + comboBox1.Text + "'  ;";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDB = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            myReader = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                double sPrice = myReader.GetDouble("Price");
                string sDesc = myReader.GetString("Description");
                txtPrice.Text = sPrice.ToString();
                txtDesc.Text = sDesc;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }

    int total;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);

        int num1 = int.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
        int num2 = int.Parse(txtTotal.Text);

        total = num1 + num2;

        txtTotal.Text = total.ToString();

    }

    private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string constring = "server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        string Query = "Select * from dbinfo.tbladvance;";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDB = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        con.Open();
        myReader = cmdDB.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            for (int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
            {
                string sName = myReader.GetString("Names");
                string removelistitem = sName;
                if (listBox1.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n);
                }
            }





        }
        con.Close();


    }
```

i'm using mysql by the way, Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I can explain some points of interest in your supplied code. There are several things that are not necessarily wrong, but unnecessary and error prone. I will point these out beginning with the severity of each unnecessary code snippet.

First, please look at the lines below…

```
string constring = "server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
string Query = "Select * from dbinfo.tbladvance;";
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmdDB = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
MySqlDataReader myReader;
```

The code above is in the `fillCombo` method. Here it appears you are connecting to and querying (a `DataTable` I am guessing from the name `dbinfo.tbladvance`) a data base and using the `DataTable` in that query to fill the combo box with strings from a column named “Names”. Then the connection is closed.

This is fine since one would assume you would only need to do this once. Now let’s move on to the next method in the code `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`. This event method fires every time the combo box selection changes.

```
string constring = "server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
string Query = "Select * from dbinfo.tbladvance where Names='" + comboBox1.Text + "'  ;";
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constring);
MySqlCommand cmdDB = new MySqlCommand(Query, con);
MySqlDataReader myReader;
```

Here it appears you are again opening a connection to a database. This time the query is to get the match where `comboBox1.Text` matches the string in the data tables’s column named “Names”. The reason you are doing this is that you need to get the price and description of the selected package. After the info is returned from the database, these values are placed into the appropriate text boxes. Then you close the connection and exit.

I could be wrong about this but, a possible issue with the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` method is that it does this opening and closing to the database EVERY TIME the user changes the combo box selection. This is unnecessary since the list of values in the combo box NEVER change.

The reason the code needs to keep querying the database is that the code never saves the first query. Looking at the `fillCombo()` method, you will see that the code is getting this data from a column whose name is `Names`. Looking at the `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` method it appears there are also two other columns in this database called: `Price` and `Description`. Assuming this data is static while the user is using the program, then saving the data (Name, Price, Description) to a `DataTable` would make things not only easier but would reduce the number of queries to your database to one (1).

If the data changes in real time and the user needs to have access to this new info in real time then you may want to consider a different approach, however this does not appear to be the case from the code supplied.

Point of the above harangue is that you should consider reading the needed data into a `DataTable`. Then use this `DataTable` to perform your queries. This will eliminate the need to keep opening and closing the database and will unclutter the code.

Second: total cost: the button click method looks mysterious and obviously does not work. Following the code, it appears that when the user presses the button the currently selected item in the combo box is placed into the list box. Then some kind of weird totaling is going on but from what you describe it appears you want to update the `txtTotal` text box with the total amount of all the “Packages” listed in the `listBox1`.

If this is correct, then you will have to keep track of this total with a variable and it appears you have one called `total`. This variable will need to be updated and redisplayed whenever an item is added to the list or removed. Juggling this global variable is not difficult, but really is unnecessary. Since the total price is dependent on what items are in the list, then it may be easier to create a method that loops through the list and returns a total from all the items in the list box. This will eliminate the need to have a global `total` variable and would be one line of code when adding or deleting items in the list box. Example: the code below loops through all the items in the list box and returns a total of all the items in the list. Keep in mind, the code below uses a `DataTable` `PackagesData` as described above where column 1 is “Package”, column 2 is “Price” and column 3 is “Description” all columns are strings.

```
private double GetTotal() {
  double grandTotal = 0;
  double curTotal = 0;
  foreach (string curDesc in listBox1.Items) {
    foreach (DataRow curRow in PackagesData.Rows) {
      if (curRow.ItemArray[2] != null && curRow.ItemArray[1] != null) {
        if (curDesc.Equals(curRow.ItemArray[2].ToString())) {
          double.TryParse(curRow.ItemArray[1].ToString(), out curTotal);
          grandTotal += curTotal;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return grandTotal;
}
```

Third: Double click an item in the list box to remove it and update the total. Again this uses a `DataTable` and the above method.

```
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int selectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
  if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
    txtTotal.Text = GetTotal().ToString();
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense and helps. If you make a data table with the columns you want, it should unclutter the current methods and make things easier. You also may consider making a "Package" class. Good Luck